# Creating a two dimensional array from a Dapper result

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

Is this the least amount of code I can use to convert a Dapper query result to a two dimensional array?

```
var array =
    cn.Query(@"SELECT Id, Desc FROM Things")
        .Select<object, ArrayList>(d =>
        {
            return new ArrayList {((dynamic) d).Id, ((dynamic) d).Desc };
        });
```

I am basically constructing a result to be returned as a json response like this:

```
[
  [1, "Thing one"],
  [2, "Thing two"],
  [3, "Thing two"],
]
```

Serialising `array` using:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
```

produces the correct result so it does the job, I'm just wondering if there's a shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about the `Dapper` syntax, but what about dropping the `ArrayList`, but instead returning `object[]` inside the select and call `ToArray()` at the end:

```
var array =
    cn.Query(@"SELECT Id, Desc FROM Things")
        .Select(d => new object[] { d.Id, d.Desc })
        .ToArray();
```

This will give you an `object[,]`.

If you dont mind a result of `dynamic[,]` you can use an even shorter version, my omitting specifying the actual array type:

```
.Select(d => new [] { d.Id, d.Desc })
```

Comment: That does the trick and in fact can be reduced further: `.Select(d => { return new object[] {  d.Id, d.Desc };  });`

Comment: @Kev: And that can be reduced further: `.Select(d => new object[] { d.Id, d.Desc });` and probably `.Select(d => new[] { d.Id, d.Desc });`.

Comment: @Gabe - ah well spotted, so it can...bad R# not picking that up :). And this is why we love Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gabe not that it matters, by using the last sample you would have an dynamic[,] in the end rather than object[,] ;)

Comment: @Kev: If the shorter one works, why not edit the answer to reflect that?

Comment: @Gabe Modified the answer to reflect both `object[,]` and `dynamic[,]` thx for the suggestions

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Nancy Framework. If I output it to array, the json output will not have parameter name.

If I use the IEnumerable with the object class and output it to JSON, it will nicely format my JSON output.

```
IEnumerable IncomingAlerts = cn.Query(@"SELECT QUERY");
return Response.AsJson(new { results = IncomingAlerts } );
```

Everything will be formatted nicely. Magically.